# Royden 7.2 Exercise 22: Inequality for the Indefinite Integral of an $L^p[a, b]$ function

Tags: real-analysis, holder-inequality

The following is Exercise 22 from Royden $\S$7.2:

> For $1 \leq p < \infty$, if the absolutely continuous function $F : [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is the indefinite integral of an $L^p[a, b]$ function $f$, then there is a constant $M > 0$ such that for any partition $\{a = x_0 < x_1 < \cdots < x_n = b\}$ of $[a, b]$,
> $$
> \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{|F(x_k) - F(x_{k - 1})|^p}{|x_k - x_{k - 1}|^{p - 1}} \leq M
> $$

So far, what I have gotten is that for each $k$,
$$
\frac{|F(x_k) - F(x_{k - 1})|^p}{|x_k - x_{k - 1}|^{p - 1}} = \frac{|\int_{x_{k - 1}}^{x_k} f|^p}{|x_k - x_{k - 1}|^{p - 1}} \leq \frac{\int_{x_{k - 1}}^{x_k} |f|^p}{|x_k - x_{k - 1}|^{p - 1}}
$$ Now, I can certainly bound the numerator $\int_{x_{k - 1}}^{x_k} |f|^p$ with $\|f\|_p^p$ since $f$ is $L^p$ but I don't know what to do with the denominator. Is there a trick to apply Holder's Inequality here? Any hints are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Suppose $p >1$ By Holder's inequality $|\int_{x_{k-1}}^{x_k} f| \leq (\int |f|^{p})^{1/p} (\int _{x_{k-1}}^{x_k} 1^{q})^{1/q}$ where $\frac 1 p+\frac1 q=1$.  Note that $q=\frac p {p-1}$. For $p=1$ the proof is much simpler.

Comment: Thank you, I see it now: since $p/q =p - 1$, $(\int_{x_{k - 1}}^{x_k} 1^q)^{p/q} = |x_k - x_{k - 1}|^{p - 1}$ and I can use that to cancel off the denominator.